# How to Create video From given images using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want source code for creating video from given images using opencv and python2.7. I try this code but it gives me an error of NoneType object has no attribute 'shape'

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
img3 = cv2.imread('3.jpg')

height , width , layers =  img1.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi',-1,1,(width,height))

video.write(img1)
video.write(img2)
video.write(img3)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
img3 = cv2.imread('3.jpg')

height , width , layers =  img1.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi',-1,1,(width,height))

video.write(img1)
video.write(img2)
video.write(img3)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()

Comment: that is code and sorry for uploading image

Comment: i edited question please help

Comment: Ok, now I get the same error, good job. This error happens because there is no `1.jpg` in the folder

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pitfall when assigning file-path that is relative. You are probably running the script with a command such as:

```
python somefolder/myscript.py
```

And you think that because `1.jpg` and the rest of the pictures are in the same folder `somefolder` that you've done well. That is not the case. Python understands your desire for `1.jpg` as being in the same folder that you used when running the script, so it searches it not in `somefolder` but in the parent of `somefolder`, because that's where you were when you ran the script.

Solutions:

1. Run the script only from the folder it's in (which isn't very useful)
2. Make the path absolute - replace `1.jpg` with `/full/path/to/1.jpg` (and do that for all the images of course)
3. Make the path relative to the script, using the `__file__` property and `os.path` module: `img1_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '1.jpg')`